# How to avoid repeated nested loading of packages?

Tags: packages, contexts

Suppose my main program depends on functions provided by package A and B, while package B also loads package A "privately". Now package A can be accessed from the main program via the context

```
A`
```

as well as

```
B`Private`A`
```

This suggests that Mathematica has loaded package A repeatedly, which is an inefficiency. Is it possible to avoid this, e.g. using some mechanism similar to "include guards" in C/C++?

Comment: Can you give details about what packages you are dealing with? Loading packages "privately" is not a standard thing to do, and even takes extra work to achieve. Normally, packages are loaded with `Needs`, which automatically avoids double-loading, no extra work required on your part.

Comment: The only instance of "private loading" I am aware of is with packages that use my own LTemplate package. LTemplate is explicitly designed to be loaded this way: there are good reasons for it. If your question happens to concern LTemplate, please make that explicit.

Comment: I agree we need more information, and to know what you mean by loading privately. For me that just means putting the `Needs` statement after the ```Begin["`Private`"]```, which does *not* create the context ```B`Private`A```.

Comment: I've been loading packages explicitly using `Get["packageName.wl"]`, because I ran into various inconveniences with `Needs`, e.g. I needed to set up the proper default loading paths, and needed the package file name to agree with the package context name. I use the `Get` statement to load package A after `Begin["\`Private\`"]` inside package B. I just checked $ContextPath, and realized that `B\`Private\`A` isn't actually created, so I stand corrected, but the double loading issue remains. Presumably I need to look into using `Needs` properly again.

Comment: You would have to explain why `Needs` is problematic for you, since it has been designed specifically to avoid loading the package more than once. When you call `Get` on the package, you of course get it loaded every time again, this is explicitly the contract of `Get`.

Comment: Yes, you can use "include guards" the same way is in C. For example, have `Get["pack1.wl"]` set a global variable `PACK1=1` and check if this variable is set before doing the `Get`.

Comment: OK, I looked into `Needs` again. `Needs["context\`","file"]` works fine for me as I can specify non-standard file locations, so the problem is solved.

Comment: A bit off topic, but when the package source file has been changed, running `Needs` again will not reload the package, so `Get` is more convenient during interactive development / testing of a package.